# How to report confusion matrix of Random Forest classifier on test set using R?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

First of all, I have to say that I'm newbie in working with R. Anyway, I'm going to apply Random Forest classifier on my data set using R. To do this, I beforehand divided my data set into training set and test set, using SPSS. After creating two separate data sets, I incorporated my training set into the associated function of R; that is, `randomForest`. It have run very well but only reported confusion matrix on training set, not test set.

I would like to ask how can one report confusion matrix calculated using Random Forest classifier on test set rather than training set?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to type `?predict.randomForest` in your R command line to see the syntax for predictions. If you are just interested in the confusion matrix with cutoff of 0.5, you can set `type="response"` and then generate your confusion matrix based on those results. If you want to be able to set your own cutoff, you can get the probabilities with `type='prob'`.

There are various functions which take a set of class labels and predictions and returns a confusion matrix. One such function is described [here](https://rforge.net/doc/packages/SDMTools/confusion.matrix.html) as part of the SDMTools package. The threshold dividing the two classes may be changed by the user; by default, it is 0.5.